# iOS sort CoreData Result - kind of parent-child relationship

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, uipickerview

I'm a bit stuck here with a simple question:

I have objects (coming via rest) stored locally with coredata.
Within coredata entitie i have the following attributes:

- catID (int16)
- parentID (int16)
- title (String)

This is to have a simple list of categories the user can choose from in a pickerView later in the app. The field catID is a unique ID identifying each category. The parentID holds the catID of the master category. If the parentID = 0, the category is a master category (root-level).

I need to load the list of categories in a pickerview to let the user choose from. 
The List within the PickerView should displayed like:

```
MainCategory 1
MainCategory 2
    SubCategory 2.1
    SubCategory 2.2
MainCategory 3
MainCategory 4
    SubCategory 4.1
```

How can i load all categories as objects in a let's say NSArray and have the categories sorted the correct way? Categories on level 2 (where parentID != 0) have to appear right after their master category in NSArray to appear correct in the pickerView.
Techincally Categories and SubCategories are objects of the same type. Only the attribute `parentID` tells if the object is a category or a subcategory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you expand a bit your question?

I don't know if it's what you want, but to sort a NSSet you can do it this way

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"theKeyToOrder" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];   

NSArray * sortedArray = [TheCoreDataResultNSSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

EDIT:

You can create a NSMutableArray and add the elements.

something like this:

```
NSMutableArray * sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (parentCategory in parentCategories) {
    [sortedArray addObject:parentCategory];
        for (child in parentCategory){
            [sortedArray addObject:child];
        }
}
```

You just need a CoreData result with just the parentCategories, and then use the child/parent relationship to add the children.

EDIT2: Sorry, I didn't see you don't have a parent/child relationship, I think you should change the parentID for a relationship. Anyways, you can do what I said, just take the parents, and then in the for, take the categories where parentID is the current Category

Comment: I'm using sorting within the app. I have a parent-child relationship of the same objects here, what makes it not easy i think.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at Coredata for what it is - an object graph manager - rather than a database.

My personal choice would be to create a relationship (and its corresponding inverse) pointing to the entity itself.

So you have a `Category` entity, a `childCategories` one to many relationship and a `parentCategory` one to one relationship as its inverse.

This way you can create your categories as normal and make the appropriate connections i.e.

```
Category *childCat = ...
Category *parentCat = ...
childCat.parentCategory = parentCat;
```

And then fetching is just a matter of deciding how you want to do it. You could fetch all `Category` entities that have no parents (i.e. they are the master categories) and then for each master category, travel through the relationship to find the `childCategories`.

Comment: This meand that i still would to first query all Categories and then check in an additional fetch, if there are sub-Categories?

Comment: Not really, you only do one fetch to find all of the master categories and then access the subcategories via the entity relationship.